# Error "actual and format arguments lists differ in length"

Tags: java, constructor, compiler-errors, validation

I cannot understand this error, despite my research throughout this website. At first the program ran, but it gave me a *"y"* as a line, and the validator choices were *"n","n","n"* all in one. So, I had a look around in my program, found it, solved it. Now I'm faced with this `actual and format arguments lists differ in length` problem. I've tried various things, like changing the variable type, using different variables... so on so forth.

Here's my code.

```
 /*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package roshambo;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Owner
 */
public class Roshambo {


    private String name;

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        String choice = "y";
        String player;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random random = new Random();
        char[] ch = new char[]{'r','p','s'};
        int r = random.nextInt(ch.length);
        char raCh = ch[r];

        while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
            System.out.println("Welcome to Roshambo!");
            System.out.println("");

            //System.out.print("Please enter your name here - ");
            //String player = sc.nextLine();

            String player1 = Validator.getRequiredString("Please enter your name here - ",player);

            String roshambo = sc.nextLine();
            String roshambo1 = Validator.getChoiceString1("Please choose Rock, Paper or Scissors. (R/P/S) - ",'r','p','s');


            choice = getChoiceString("Play Again? (y/n): ","y","n");
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
    public static String getChoiceString(String prompt, String str1, String str2)
    {
        boolean isValid = false;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String choice = "";

        while (isValid == false) {
        System.out.print(prompt);
        choice = sc.next();
        if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase(str1) || choice.equalsIgnoreCase(str2)) {
            isValid = true;

        }
        sc.nextLine();

        }
        return choice;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I'll also add in my Validator code, as I think the problems lies between those two.

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package roshambo;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * @author Owner
 */
public class Validator {

    // force the user to enter a string
    public static String getRequiredString(String prompt) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = "";
        boolean isValid = false;

        while (isValid == false) {
            System.out.print(prompt);
            input = sc.nextLine();
            if (input.equals("")) {
                System.out.println("Error! This entry is required. Try again.");
            }
            else {
                isValid = true;
            }
        }
        return input;
    }
    // force the user to enter one of three strings
    public static String getChoiceString1(String prompt, String str1, String str2, String str3) {
        String input = "";
        boolean isValid = false;

        while (isValid == false) {
            input = getRequiredString(prompt);
            if (input.equalsIgnoreCase(str1) || input.equalsIgnoreCase(str2) || input.equalsIgnoreCase(str3)) {
                isValid = true;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Error! Entry must be '"+ str1 +"', '"+ str2 +"', or '"+ str3 +"'. Try again.");  
            }
        }
        return input;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **getRequiredString method** in **Validator class** is expecting a single **String argument**, you are passing two arguments, String and a Player(you should however be getting another compiler error, saying cant find player, as you commented it out) in your method call.

```
public static String getRequiredString(String prompt) { // is pnly expecting one String argument.

    String player1 = Validator.getRequiredString("Please enter your name here - ",player);// passing two arguments
```

Just pass **prompt** from your **method call** and the error would disappear.

```
 String player1 = Validator.getRequiredString("Please enter your name here - ");
```

Comment: Herpaderp on my part. Thank you very much. Time for the next error! Onwards!